# How to align buttons to left in navbar

Tags: angular-material, angular8

Trying to align some menu buttons to left with Angular Material

like on the [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jrEB.png)

```
 <div>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <a mat-button class="menu" routerLink="/">
      <span>Just a menu</span>
    </a>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
      <a mat-button routerLink="/component1">Button1</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/component2">Button2</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/component3">Button3</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

How can I do this in proper way and still have responsive site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox like this:

Add a class to your div and add container to specify "right and left block"

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true" class="container">
      <div>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/component1">Button1</a>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/component2">Button2</a>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/component3">Button3</a>
      </div>
      <div>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/login">Login</a>
          <a mat-button routerLink="/logout">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The 3 buttons will be on the left and Login, Logon on the right

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout for easier alignment

After installing the library, use this snippet in your code

```html
<div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <a mat-button routerLink="/component1">Button1</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/component2">Button2</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/component3">Button3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```